# Rails view ivars spontaneously combusting in ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, ivar

I have a Rails 3 / ruby 1.9.2 webapp.  Every so often - and it might only be 1 request in 100000 - I get an error report that I can't explain.

The exact error varies, but they seem to be along the lines of having an instance variable in my view suddenly become nil.  The clearest instance of this occurred recently, where this code in a helper -

```
 @swf_object_count||=0
 @swf_object_count+=1
```

- raised "NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass".  However, note that the errors are not limited to this case, and these two lines of code are meant only for illustration, not as something that can be worked around to 'solve' the problem.

The error is basically impossible to reproduce : I have never seen it myself, only seen the error reports resulting from it.  I believe the error first appeared when we switched from REE to ruby 1.9.2.

Miscellaneous details that may or may not be relevant:

- We're running ruby1.9.2p290 on Solaris 10, using unicorn forked instances
- We're not using threads or fibers (correction: our app itself doesn't, but we do use NewRelic, which has a background thread for collecting/posting stats.)
- We have a mix of .haml & .erb views, but I've only ever seen this occur from .haml.  (We don't have many .erbs, though)
- I've never seen this occur in controller code
- I've occasionally seen errors regarding "undefined method 'foomethod' for Bar", when I know for a fact that we never call Bar.foomethod.  It might be possible that this is related to the bug described above, where a Bar object spontaneously replaced a Foo ivar.

I'm pretty stumped on tracking this down.  Any suggestions, or has anyone seen anything that sounds similar?

Comment: my first thought was threads or fibers -- but you said you don't use them. hmm... could this be triggered from a stale session?

Comment: hmm.. this error really should never happen because @swf_object_count will always be set to 0 if it was nil ... by the first line.. hmm..

Answer (score 0):

my first thought was threads or fibers -- but you said you don't use them. hmm... could this be triggered from a stale session?

this is really a very broad and loosely defined question..

Perhaps you could write a script to analyze your log files, and try to narrow down when / in which routes this happens. But that's pretty hard to debug also, because you probably made a couple of code changes along the way, some of which have produced valid errors which may look similar.

It can happen that Unicorn instances die and then they get restarted.. this could upset the current session.
This might be something you may want to experiment with -- e.g. use a test-environment with two unicorns, kill one mid-session and see how that affects your logs.

You should probably install a facility where your Rails server emails you a detailed log record whenever an exception is triggered.. that's probably the best way to get more visibility into what's happening there..

e.g.: this Gem in your Gemfile:

```
# Receive exception notifications from production
gem 'exception_notification_rails3', :require => 'exception_notifier'
```

and in your config/environments/production.rb file:

```
  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
    :email_prefix => "[Exception] ",
    :sender_address => %{"Exception Notifier" <your-system@your-domain.com>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{person1@your-domain.com person2@your-domain.com}
```

See also: 
    https://github.com/railsware/exception_notification

Comment: "this is really a very broad and loosely defined question.." - yup :)

Comment: I'm already using Airbrake to collect our exceptions.  Unfortunately, it basically tells me that there is little or no pattern to the requests that cause this.  They're all on different pages, from different users & ips.

Comment: Killing off unicorns mid-request is a good idea, though - I'll see if I can reproduce anything that way...

Comment: probably also a good idea to look further at the logged exceptions, and try to re-create those scenarios by poking at a copy of the application.

Comment: how much swap space have you configured on your system?

Comment: It's just limited by the amount of free space - currently about 3TB.

Comment: it you should add swap space.. if there is no swap space configured, and for some reason all physical memory is used, processes can die inexplicably.. that could cause pretty bad problems in production

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating view ivars in your helpers is a *terrible* idea. I'm not sure why you're getting the concurrency issues you're getting, but I suspect they will go away if you structure your code differently.

Perhaps you can just have the helper calculate the increment values, and in your view do something like

`@swf_object_count + swf_increment_helper_value`

Comment: "Manipulating view ivars in your helpers is a terrible idea" - why do you think that?  In this case, the ivar is only ever referenced from inside the helper - it's generating a number of flash objects, each of which needs a unique id on the page.

Comment: Your view ivars should go straight from the controller to the view, or else you run the risk of introducing subtle bugs such as you're currently experiencing. Also, manipulating view ivars in the helper couples it far too closely to the controller and view. In your case, if you need the value of the view ivar in the helper, then pass it in as an argument -- do not manipulate it directly.

Comment: Also, if your helper is generating a number of Flash objects, it sounds like it may want to be a partial, not a helper.

Comment: Another explanation of why this is bad practice: Helpers are modules (that get included into the view class). It is generally a bad idea for a module to directly touch the instance variables of the class it's been included into -- that makes too many assumptions about the host class. Use the host class's interface instead.

Comment: `ActionView::Base` includes helpers by 1: getting helpers from the controller and setting them as a class attribute with method `class_attribute`, 2: creating a new `Class` as the view context, 3: including the helpers in the `helpers` class attribute in the new class. I haven't looked further into this but maybe the "ivars" being modified in the helper are actually being turned into class vars on `ActionView::Base`, which would cause your problems when two views are being rendered at the same time - but only in production mode.

Comment: If that's the case, then other very low-frequency problems that do not raise exceptions might be occurring as well. I could be completely wrong so here's the source of `ActionView::Base`. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb

Comment: @jimworm: You probably should post this as an answer of your own instead of a comment on mine. Interesting; I didn't know about the `class_attribute` call. Just another reason not to touch view ivars in helpers...

Comment: They're just regular modules getting mixed into the view context, so ivars in there don't become class variables.